# Ajax Id Auto Incrementing

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I will probably sound or look dumb by this but I need to learn.  Check out the following part of a code:

```
       $('.buttonclass').click(function(){ 
        var button_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
     $('#'+button_id).click(function(){   

           var yes = $("input#yes").val();
    if (yes == "") {
   return false;
   }
var id = $("input#id").val();
    if (id == "") {
  return false;
}

        var dataString = 'yes='+ yes + '&id=' + id;



            //try insted this    //alert (dataString);return false;  
              $.ajax({  type: "POST",  dataType:'HTML', 
              //or the appropiate type of data you are getting back 
               url: "http://www.edshaer.com/EdinburgCISD/Gorena/Gorena.php",      data: dataString,


                //in the php file do $email = $_POST['email']; 



                  //not a good practice but you can try with it and without it 
                   success: function(data) {  



                $("#div").hide(data).fadeOut();
                   $("#div").html(data);
                   $("#div").show(data).fadeIn();


                   // Change the content of the message element    

                      // Fade the element back in 
                         }    });
                            //ajax ends 
                                         return false; });
                                         //click ends   
                                          });//document ready ends
```

My button ID that is being submitted in my html page is sending random numbers.  For example
It can be:

```
                $("#383").click(function() {
```

or it can be:

```
                  $("#521").click(function() {
```

My question is, how do I do it to auto increment the ID of the button clicked so that no matter what ID number is clicked it will still run the run the code smoothly...  Right now I have this:

```
       $('.buttonclass').click(function(){ 
      var button_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
          $('#'+button_id).click(function(){
```

Hopefully someone can help me...  let me know if you need more info...  Thank you in advanced...

Here is part of my HTML code... Hopefully it will be a little more understandable...

```
    <?php
   $data3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `EdinburgCISDGorenamessage` 
   ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 0, 100") 
       or die(mysql_error()); 
          echo "<div id=\"div\">    <table align=\"center\" width=\"570\">"; 
        while($info3 = mysql_fetch_array( $data3 )) 
          { 

           $id = $info3['ID'];
          }
       ?>

       <form name="contact" id="post" method="post" action="">
         <input  id="id" value="<?php echo $id?>"/>
           <input type="submit" class="buttonclass" id="<?php echo $id?>" name="<?php echo $id?>" value="Yes" />

       <input type="submit" id="no<?php echo $id ?>" name="no<?php echo $id ?>" value=" No " /> </form>
```

I don' want to provide the whole code because its too messy and it doesn't go with the question...  Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Can you post the code of the buttons? How do you print them in your html?

Comment: Just posted the updates  I hope you understand them.

Comment: Going to bed... Hopefully someone  can help... Goodnight...

Answer (score 2):

Use a class instead. Add a class to the button, and an incremental id you give it while printing it out in your html (I suppose you echo buttons in a loop?), and then just use one snippet:

```
$('.buttonclass').click(function(){

   var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#'+button_id).click(function(){
     // your function here
      alert(button_id); // just to see if ID is retrieved
   )};
});
```

So, if you have

```
<button id="325" class="buttonclass" type="button">BUTTON 325</button>
<button id="150" class="buttonclass" type="button">BUTTON 150</button>
```

The ID of the button you click is retrieved only when you press it

Comment: What does it mean "it didn't work"? The code works in retrieving the ID because I use it often in my code; what's happening? What does the JS console tells you?

Comment: I am thinking its because its a submit input and not a button... sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. You already have a classname on the button, so the `.click()` is captured, why do you need the ID, and moreover, why do you need to find it so bad?

Please elaborate more and we will do our best to help you :)

Comment: If I have 30 submits in a loop with the same class then it will never be able to distinguish one from the other unless I place a specific ID or make the class more specific.  Say for example my submit button was a delete button.  Then what is going to happen is that it is going to delete everything since they all have the same class.  If I write a specific number for each then only that one will get deleted. Thats what I am trying to reach.  And its not like im dying for the code. I already have it done in php.  I just wanted to convert it to ajax to make it nicer and cleaner.  Thank you again